# dataset not giving value using oracle

Tags: .net, oracle

I am using oracle conection to get data from database and then i tried to store data in dataset, which i further use to export in excel sheet.

I use the oracle connection as:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(database);
            con.Open();
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(query,con);

            con.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();             
            da.Fill(ds);
```

but this dataset is not giving any data.
I also ran my query in database which is giving perfect data.

Please help me out.

Comment: is there anyone to solve my problem..

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fill the dataset using oracle database. Please given below code:
Steps to Create Visual C# .NET Application

1. Create a new Visual C# Windows Application project. Form1 is added to the project by default.
2. Drag a DataGrid control and a Button control to Form1. DataGrid1 and Button1 are added to Form1 by default.
3. Add the following code after the first line, "using System.Data," in the Code window:

   using System.Data.OleDb;
4. Add the following code to the Button1_Click event:

   > OleDbConnection cnOra = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA;Data
   >   Source=myOracleServer;" + "user id=myUID;password=myPWD;" + "persist
   >   security info=false;");   OleDbCommand cmdPerson = new OleDbCommand +
   >   ("{call PackPerson.allPerson({resultset 3, ssn, fname, lname})}",
   >   cnOra);         OleDbDataAdapter daPerson = new
   >   OleDbDataAdapter(cmdPerson);
   >
   > ```
   > cnOra.Open();
   >
   > DataSet ds = new DataSet(); daPerson.Fill(ds,"Person"); this.dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Person"];
   >
   > cnOra.Close();
   > ```

for more details please visit: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310101

Comment: but that i am doing for console application